# Run kafka consumer without specifying partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am learning Kafka recently, and my consumers can't consume any records unless I specify the `--parititon 0` parameter. In other words I can NOT consume records like:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.10:9092 --topic first-topic
```

but works like:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.10:9092 --topic first-topic --partition 0
```

THE MAIN PROBLEM IS, when I moved to java code, my `KafkaConsumer` class can't fetch records, and I need to know how to specify the `partition` number in java `KafkaConsumer` ?!

my current java code is:

```
public class ConsumerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger((ConsumerDemo.class.getName()));

        String bootstrapServer = "127.0.0.10:9092";
        String groupId = "my-kafka-java-app";
        String topic = "first-topic";

        // create consumer configs
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        //properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, partition);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        // create consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

        // subscribe consumer to our topic
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic)); //means subscribtion to one topic

        // poll for new data
        while(true){
            //consumer.poll(100); old way
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records =
                    consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
                logger.info("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: "+ record.value() );
                logger.info("Partition: " + record.partition() + ", Offset: "+ record.offset());
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce while using a fresh consumer group. Did you modify any Kafka server properties? What version of Kafka and the clients are you using?

Comment: In other words, please show the output of `kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.10:9092 --group my-kafka-java-app --describe`... And why `127.0.0.10`? This address isn't a proper loopback IP or private LAN address

Comment: @OneCricketeer, regarding the IP, it is a hypothitical one, while in our I put the server's real name when I execute.. it is not a big deal

Comment: @OneCricketeer, regarding the output of the command, it is showing:

`Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CoordinatorNotAvailableException: The coordinator is not available.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CoordinatorNotAvailableException: The coordinator is not available.`

Comment: the version is `2.1.0-cdh6.2.1` on top of cloudera

Comment: Well, you needed to give the real ip to that command

Comment: @OneCricketeer, for sure I put the correct server name while execution, the ip above is only an example for StackOverFlow posting.

Comment: Okay, well, coordinator should be available. Otherwise, sounds like the cluster isn't healthy or there's other network issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of inspection, my solution came out to be using `consumer.assign` and `consumer.seek` instead of using `consumer.subscribe` and without specifying the groupId. But I feel there should be a more optimal solution

the java code will be as:

```
        // create consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);

        // subscribe consumer to our topic
        //consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic)); //means subscription to one topic
        // using assign and Seek, are mostly used to replay data or fetch a specific msg
        TopicPartition  partitionToReadFrom = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
        long offsetToReadFrom = 15L;
        // assign
        consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partitionToReadFrom));

        // seek: for a specific offset to read from
        consumer.seek(partitionToReadFrom, offsetToReadFrom);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is correct. You don't need to specify the partition when subscribing to a topic. Maybe your consumer group has already consumed all messages in the topic and has committed the latest offsets.

Make sure new messages are being produced when you run your application or create a new consumer group to consume from the beginning (if you keep the `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` set to "earliest")

Comment: The problem is I even run the consumer before the producer, and when I do that in the shell command, it only works when I specify the --partition. And even in the java code it is not consuming records even if I run more than 1 consumer in parallel. And I have tried to change the group_id ..and didn't work

Answer (score -1):

As the name implies, the `ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG` property aims to configure a [*Partition Assignment Strategy*](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy) and no to set a fixed partition as instructed by the command line.

The default strategy used is the `RangeAssignor` which can be changed, for example to a `StickyAssignor` as follows:

```
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,StickyAssignor.class.getName());
```

You can read more about [*Kafka Client Side Assignment Proposal*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Client-side+Assignment+Proposal).

Comment: The strategy line is commented out, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer, exactly, I don't think this makes an issue in the current case